# How can I make arrows touch boxed expressions in tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-cd

I have a diagram that is structurally like this:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  \boxed{B} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{f}"'] \arrow[r, "{x}"]
& \boxed{C} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{g}"'] \arrow[r, dotted, "{y}"] 
& \boxed{D} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{h}"']
\\
  \boxed{E} & \boxed{F} & \boxed{G}
\end{tikzcd}
```

It produces the following output:

> [image: boxed example output]

How can I make the arrows just touch the boxes so they look connected? Is tikzcd the best way to approach this?

Comment: The vertical arrows too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option may be to drop `\boxed` and use `draw` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw}}]
  B \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{f}"'] \arrow[r, "{x}"]
& C \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{g}"'] \arrow[r, dotted, "{y}"] 
& D \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{h}"']
\\
  E & F & G
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could set the inner and outer seps to 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt}}]
  \boxed{B} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{f}"'] \arrow[r, "{x}"]
& \boxed{C} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{g}"'] \arrow[r, dotted, "{y}"] 
& \boxed{D} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{h}"']
\\
  \boxed{E} & \boxed{F} & \boxed{G}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want the horizontal arrows too touch, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={outer xsep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt}}]
  \boxed{B} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{f}"'] \arrow[r, "{x}"]
& \boxed{C} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{g}"'] \arrow[r, dotted, "{y}"] 
& \boxed{D} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{h}"']
\\
  \boxed{E} & \boxed{F} & \boxed{G}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can just shorten the arrows by a negative amount. I added a style `touching` that extends the arrows by the standard inner plus outer seps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{touching/.style={shorten >=-4pt,shorten <=-4pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \boxed{B} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{f}"'] \arrow[r, "{x}",touching]
& \boxed{C} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{g}"'] \arrow[r, dotted, "{y}",touching] 
& \boxed{D} \arrow[d, hookrightarrow, "{h}"']
\\
  \boxed{E} & \boxed{F} & \boxed{G}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "If you really think this is a good idea" -- does that mean you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: @AlexReinking I will drop this statement. But yes, I personally do not find this pretty, but this is just an opinion.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The "touching" solution is pretty much perfect.

Comment: Thanks for going even further with a way to remove the `\boxed` commands!